# Python tag max, 75th pct, 50th pct and min values in group

Tags: python, pandas

how can i check if a value within a group is the 75th pct or the 50th pct? i have a df with scores and for each group, i want to create new variables that tag the maximum, minimum, 75th pct and 50th pct score in that group. so there should be a column 'max' which is 1 if the value in the group is the max value and another column 'pct75' that is 1 if the value is at the 75th pct. i don't want the value to be 1 for all values above the 75th pct or the 50th pct but the value corresponding to these exact pcts. so there should be only 1 entry tagged in each group. thanks!

Comment: Kindly share sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `transform`

```
q2 = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(pd.Series.quantile,q=0.5)
df['isq2'] = df.value==q2
max_v = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('max')
df['ismax'] = df.value==max_v
```

For this one dose not match

```
thresh = 0.01
df['isq2'] = (df.value-q2).abs()< thresh
```

Comment: thanks but this seems to work only for max and min. isq2 was false throughout.

Comment: @atatam_anukah you should check what is the quantile mean and what is 75th pct mean here :-)

Comment: yes i think the issue is that the values don't match exactly. what can i do to get the value closest to the quantile mean or the 75th pct mean? thanks!

Comment: @atatam_anukah here we need a thresh , what is Torrance you have can treat it as 'same'